# C find string into file

Tags: c, string

This is the file *auth.txt* (username password)
paolo 1234
luca 0000
marci 1000

And this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void onexit(char *u, char *p, char *l, FILE *f, int flag);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *fp;
    char *tmp, *tmp2, *user, *pass, *line;

    printf("Inserire utente: ");
    if(scanf("%ms", &user) == EOF){
        perror("scanf");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Inserire password: ");
    if(scanf("%ms", &pass) == EOF){
        perror("scanf");
        onexit(user, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t max_length = strlen(user) + strlen(pass) + 3;
    line = malloc(max_length);
    if(line == NULL){
        perror("malloc");
        onexit(user, pass, NULL, NULL, 2);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fp = fopen("/home/pol/auth.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Errore apertura file\n");
        onexit(user, pass, line, NULL, 3);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while(!feof(fp)){
        if(fgets(line, max_length , fp) == NULL){
            perror("fgets");
            onexit(user, pass, line, fp, 4);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        tmp = strtok(line, " ");
        if(tmp == NULL){
            perror("strtok");
            onexit(user, pass, line, fp, 4);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        tmp2 = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        if(tmp2 == NULL){
            perror("strtok");
            onexit(user, pass, line, fp, 4);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if((strcmp(tmp,user) == 0) && (strcmp(tmp2,pass) == 0)){
            printf("USER: %s - PASS: %s\n", tmp, tmp2);
            onexit(user, pass, line, fp, 4);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        else{
                 continue;
        }
    }
    printf("no such user or pwd into DB\n");
    onexit(user, pass, line, fp, 4);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

void onexit(char *u, char *p, char *l, FILE *f, int flag){
    if(flag == 1){
        free(u);
    }
    if(flag == 2){
        free(u);
        free(p);
    }
    if(flag == 3){
        free(u);
        free(p);
        free(l);
    }
    if(flag == 4){
        free(u);
        free(p);
        free(l);
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

EDIT: another problem!
if i want to test `luca` with `0000` i got:

Inserire utente: luca
Inserire password: 0000
strtok: Success

and the program stop.
It works only with 1st and 3rd input but not with the 2nd!
why??

Comment: Edited my answer with another suggestion; we'll get this eventually!

Comment: Should I have commented on my latest edit as well, to let you notice that? In any case, I believe you should now be able to accept an answer for this question and be done with it. Any more problems which crop up, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `while` loop will only go through one iteration:

```
while(!feof(fp)){
  // ...
  if((strcmp(tmp,user) == 0) && (strcmp(tmp2,pass) == 0)){  // if match, exit
    printf("USER: %s - PASS: %s\n", tmp, tmp2);
    onexit(user, pass, line, fp, 4);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
  else{                                                     // else exit
    printf("no such user or pwd into DB\n");
    onexit(user, pass, line, fp, 4);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

...which seems a little funny.  Do you really want to exit if the first line you read doesn't match?

---

**Edit:**

<s>Another problem: you need to allocate space for `user` and `pass` before you send them into `scanf`:</s>

```
char *user;
scanf("%ms", &user);  // error
```

Instead of that, you could try something like:

```
char user[100];
scanf("%ms", &user);  // now user actually has some space to store data
```

(In your version, `scanf` will try to write data into the location that `user` points to, but `user` just points at a random location in memory, so who knows what will happen.)

Whoops, as @MvG pointed out, this is fine.  I wasn't familiar with the "%ms" POSIX extension.

---

**Edit 2**:

Say you enter the username `uu` and the password `pp`.  Because of this:

```
size_t max_length = strlen(user) + strlen(pass) + 3;
```

...you'll set `max_length` to `2 + 2 + 3`, or `7`.  [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) will read data until it encounters at most `max_length-1` characters or a newline character.  That means when you get inside your `while` loop, you'll only try to read at most `7-1` or `6` characters per iteration, which doesn't seem right.

For example, if your password file contains:

```
paolo 1234
luca 0000
marci 1000
```

...then `line` will get the following values:

1. `"paolo "` (with a trailing space)
2. `"1234"`
3. `"luca 0"`
4. `"000"`
5. `"marci "` (again, with a trailing space)
6. `"1000"`

Instead of basing `max_length` on the current username and password that you've read in, make `max_length` a large fixed value (like `100`).

Comment: lol you're right xD i've written else{continue;} and now it works XD

Comment: The `m` in `%ms` already takes care of allocation. This is a [POSIX extension](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html). The program above does not call free, so there is a memory leak, but if the db is small and the program terminates after one request, I see no problem there. Note that for `%ms` you pass the address of a pointer variable (i.e. a `char**` value), whereas for `%s` you'd pass the address of an array (i.e. a `char*` value).

Comment: So there's no need to do `char user[100]` right? So i have to correct into `scanf("%s", user)`??

Comment: @polslinux: You can keep it the way it is, I was even wrong about the memory leak, as there is no `%ms` inside the loop. _If_ you were to write `char user[100]` instead, _then_ you'd have to use `scanf("%99s", user)`. I suggest you better keep your `%ms`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your error handler is inside the while loop. If the user isn't the first in the file, you abort immediately. Beter write it this way:

```
…
        if((strcmp(tmp,user) == 0) && (strcmp(tmp2,pass) == 0)){
            printf("USER: %s - PASS: %s\n", tmp, tmp2);
            onexit(user, pass, line, fp, 4);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    printf("no such user or pwd into DB\n");
    onexit(user, pass, line, fp, 4);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

## Edit:

I can reproduce the `strtok: Success` problem when there is an entry in the database without a space in between. This might even be an empty line at the end of the file, in cases where the loop proceeds this far. In that case, the first strtok will return the whole string, and the second strtok will return NULL, thus indicating that there are no more tokens. As this is no error message, the errno status is zero, corresponding to the “error message” `Success`.

I guess in your case the problem lies in the different length of the records. You measure the length of your line read buffer by the length of the input, but some records are longer. In that case, you read part of a line and split that correctly, and at the next run you read the remainder of the line and end up with what appears like a line without a space, including the behaviour I described above.

Comment: thanks i've corrected my code! but i have another problem explained in the first post :)

Comment: i haven't understand! My db file hasn't e empty line at the end and all the entries in auth.txt have 1 space between USER PASS. I've also noticed that if i have 4 entries ONLY 1st and 3rd work but 2nd and 4th not O.o